Nextjs 14 always responds with 404 Not Found when using API routes
I am very new to next am running the following API route code from nextjs documentation (this is a file named "hello.js" in the api folder)
export default function handler(req, res) {
  res.status(200).json({ message: 'Hello from Next.js!' })
}

but fail miserably always getting 404 not found.
Of course, if I use a Route Handlers in the App Router it works fine. Can you please tell me how I can make this API route to work?

are you using app router or page router ? if you are using
Pages Router
it has a folder name pages/
and usually in the page folder there is folder name api/ then inside that you can make an api route with hello.js, hello.ts.
App Router
if you use App router it usually have app/ folder
and the way we are making the route is using route handler, and we can do it almost anywhere on the app
as long as you use route.ts or route.js, and if you want to have pages in app router then we use /name-of-the-path/pages.tsx
So if you want to have domain.com/hello then the folder is /hello/page.tsx
and if you want to have domain.com/api/hello then the folder is /api/hello/route.ts
you can't however use page.tsx and route.ts file on the same folder.
Read more the migration here :
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration

Yes I am using Pages Router option. I follow exactly what you told me (hello.js file in the API folder) and always get "404 Not found response"

can i see the repo ?

no need actually, managed to sort this out. your response was really helpful! Thanks again

maybe you can mark my answer then as accepted hehe

I have exactly the same problem with "pages" route option. I think there is a problem with the default project setting, because when I use the route api sample project from next.js github, it works perfectly, but when I move its files to my project with the same directory tree, I always get 404. How did you solve this problem?

never mind, i should use route handles in my case

sometimes when there is a problem like that just restart with clean state and add the feature one by one
